# Using image URL with parentheses as background with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url

I'm loading a bunch of files as `background-image` using jQuery and I have this image that will simply not load. The browser does not throw any error.

I know the problem is that the file name contain parentheses `()`, but I've tried all sorts of things and nothing works. This is not a duplicate [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162270/cloning-background-image-with-parenthesis-in-file-name) as the solution there does not work.

This is the URL of the file

```
http://oceanhotelsimages.com/uploads/200x150_Privilege_Lounge_OBS_05_(1).jpg
```

I've tried different things in Javascript with no luck.

```
unescape(str);

encodeURI(str)
```

Even directly replacing the characters

```
str.replace("(", "%28");
str.replace(")", "%29");
```

Even by pure desperation

```
str.replace("(", "&#40;");
str.replace(")", "&#41;");
```

Help me StackOverflow, you are my only hope.

Please do not suggest to change the file name. I do not have access to that file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought. I was missing the quotes when declaring the url of the CSS property.

```
$(this).css({
    "background-image": "url('" + someString + "')"
});
```